# How to exclude scraping results depending on children with specific class using Simple HTML DOM and cURL?

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I am scraping a certain website for specific links, which I am saving to my **$url_results** array. But want to exclude adding the link to the array if the **li** cluster, with the class of **list-items__item**, includes a child->child->child **span** with a class of **list-items__item__notice**.

**Cluster I am scraping:**

```
<li>
    <a href="" data-lpurl=""> <!--The href I am scraping-->
        <span class="list-items__item__position"></span>
        <div class="list-items__item__title">
            <span class="list-items__item__notice"> <!--I don't want to add to my array if this span is present-->
            </span>
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
```

**My PHP scraping function:**

```
$items = $html->find('li[class=list-items__item]');  
foreach($items as $post) {
    $url_results[] = $url . ($post->children(0)->href);
}
```

I am using [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) and cURL to scrape.

Comment: that class attribute isn't exactly right.

Comment: It is scraped data, so I sadly don't have any control over what classes they use.

Comment: No I meant it didn't match the class in the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding an if-sentence, checking whether the tag was empty and if so, add the `href` to my array, if not, do nothing, as below:

```
foreach($items as $post) {
    if (empty($post->children(0)->children(1)->children(0)->plaintext)) {
        $url_results[] = $url . ($post->children(0)->href);
    }
    else {}
}
```